# Using a for loop to delete an object from an array without affecting the rest of the array

Tags: javascript, loops

I need to delete an employee from an array. I need to remove the full object for that employee (all of the key value pairs) with a function that will loop through the array and check for the key value `firstName` and delete the object based on the name.

Lets say the name is "Mike".

I want to use the splice command and a for loop. this is what I have currently... but I can't get it to detect and delete the object. I just get the full list returned.

```
function employeeUpdater() {
   for (let key in obj) {
      if (obj[key] === "Theo") {
         Array.splice();
      }
   }
   return(obj)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you show your data structure and actual/expected output? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data you are working with. A [mre] in other words. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to make it easier for others to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.filter()` seems much more appropriate for your task.

```js
const data = [{ name: 'Mike' }, { name: 'Sam' }, { name: 'Sarah' }];

const filtered = data.filter(p => p.name !== 'Mike');

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to do this, you must first loop through your array of employees. I am assuming that it is called `employees`.

The array `splice()` method has two parameters (for your purpose). The parameters are `index` and `amountToDelete`. For example, doing `employees.splic(3, 1);` will delete the fourth employee from the list.

Here's how you would do it in your context:

```
employees.forEach(function(obj, index){
    for (let key in obj){
        if (obj[key] === "Theo") {
            employees.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the keys.
2. Loop through keys, using them with object to get value.
3. If found, delete, then break as there's no need to continue.
4. Profit.

   ```
   var keys = Object.keys(employees);

   keys.forEach(k => {
     if (employees[k] == "Theo") {
       delete employees[k];
       break;
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: This will mutate the original array and OP was requesting for a one which does not .

Comment: I believe you misread the title. "delete an object from an array without affecting the rest of the array" means to delete the object without deleting or affecting the other elements.

Comment: So you want to make a copy of the array first?